# How to update restricted fields with lightning-record-edit-form?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have a use case where I have created a modal for cloning a case with a bunch of custom fields to select. The values will be copied from the original case to the cloned fields with an option to allow users to update it from the modal.

The problem is some users who do not have access to certain fields, get an error stating "no such field Opportunity" for object case. For such users, I tried hiding the fields from the modal and passing the default values for the fields like shown below.

```
<lightning-record-edit-form
                    object-api-name="Case"
                    density="comfy"
                    onsuccess={handleSuccess}
                    onload={handleLoad}
                    onsubmit={submitForm}
                >
// set of Lightning input Fields
<lightning-input-field field-name="Opportunity__c" value={getOpportunity} class="slds-hidden" style="display: none"> </lightning-input-field>

</lightning-record-edit-form>

submitForm(event) {
        let fields = event.detail.fields;
        if(fields.Opportunity === undefined) {
            fields.Opportunity = this.selectedOpportunity; // forcing a value into the field
        }
        event.preventDefault();

        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    }
```

Options I am thinking. To edit the fields that the user does not have access to with an apex class (with "without sharing") to edit the fields post case creation.

Comment: Although using a class annotated without sharing, I'd just ask what the requirement is for these users to set values on a field that they shouldn't have access to? I'm always wary of doing that without drilling down into the why. If these are just defaults as well, have you considered either a Record Triggered flow running in system mode or default field values to set the defaults?